# Issues building a TypeScript monorepo project

Tags: node.js, typescript, monorepo

I have a fairly simple mono repo. It is available on GitLab
[here](https://gitlab.com/remcohaszing/koas). This uses yarn workspaces, TypeScript, Jest, `ts-jest`
and ESLint with `eslint-plugin-import`.

I am trying to properly build the project packages using TypeScript. Previously I was just
publishing the TypeScript files alongside their JavaScript code in the same directory.

My attempt to build the project is available in a GitLab merge request
[here](https://gitlab.com/remcohaszing/koas/merge_requests/27)

Now the repository follows the following layout:

```
 |- example/
 |   |- index.ts
 |   |- package.json
 |   `- tsconfig.json
 |- packages/
 |   |- koas-core/
 |   |   |- src/
 |   |   |   `- index.ts
 |   |   |- package.json
 |   |   `- tsconfig.json
 |   |- koas-status-code/
 |   |   |- src/
 |   |   |   `- index.ts
 |   |   |- package.json
 |   |   `- tsconfig.json
 |   `- more similar workspaces…
 |- package.json
 |- tsconfig.json
 `- more configuration files…
```

Some packages depend on each other. I have managed to get Jest tests and `eslint-plugin-import` to
work with this setup, but I’m having trouble building the project.

The root `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "composite": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noEmit": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "esnext",
    "paths": {
      "koas-*": ["packages/koas-*/src"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

The workspace `tsconfig.json` files look like this:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "rootDir": "src",
    "outDir": "lib"
  }
}
```

Each workspace has a `prepack` script defined in `package.json` that looks like this:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "prepack": "tsc --noEmit false"
  }
}
```

The `main` field refers to `lib`.

If I run `yarn workspace koas-status-code prepack`, I get the following error:

```
$ tsc --noEmit false
error TS6059: File 'koas/packages/koas-core/src/SchemaValidationError.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'koas/packages/koas-status-code'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

error TS6059: File 'koas/packages/koas-core/src/SchemaValidationError.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'koas/packages/koas-status-code/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

error TS6059: File 'koas/packages/koas-core/src/createDefaultValidator.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'koas/packages/koas-status-code'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

error TS6059: File 'koas/packages/koas-core/src/createDefaultValidator.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'koas/packages/koas-status-code/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

error TS6059: File 'koas/packages/koas-core/src/createMatcher.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'koas/packages/koas-status-code'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

error TS6059: File 'koas/packages/koas-core/src/createMatcher.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'koas/packages/koas-status-code/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

error TS6059: File 'koas/packages/koas-core/src/index.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'koas/packages/koas-status-code'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

error TS6059: File 'koas/packages/koas-core/src/index.ts' is not under 'rootDir' 'koas/packages/koas-status-code/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

error TS6307: File 'koas/packages/koas-core/src/SchemaValidationError.ts' is not listed within the file list of project 'koas/packages/koas-status-code/tsconfig.json'. Projects must list all files or use an 'include' pattern.

error TS6307: File 'koas/packages/koas-core/src/createDefaultValidator.ts' is not listed within the file list of project 'koas/packages/koas-status-code/tsconfig.json'. Projects must list all files or use an 'include' pattern.

error TS6307: File 'koas/packages/koas-core/src/createMatcher.ts' is not listed within the file list of project 'koas/packages/koas-status-code/tsconfig.json'. Projects must list all files or use an 'include' pattern.

error TS6307: File 'koas/packages/koas-core/src/index.ts' is not listed within the file list of project 'koas/packages/koas-status-code/tsconfig.json'. Projects must list all files or use an 'include' pattern.


Found 12 errors.
```

I have also tried this `tsconfig.json` for `koas-status-code`:

```
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "../koas-core" }],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "lib"
  }
}
```

This builds the workspace, but still gives me the following error:

```
$ tsc --noEmit false
src/index.ts:1:23 - error TS6305: Output file '/home/remco/Projects/koas/packages/koas-core/lib/src/index.d.ts' has not been built from source file '/home/remco/Projects/koas/packages/koas-core/src/index.ts'.

1 import * as Koas from 'koas-core';
                        ~~~~~~~~~~~


Found 1 error.
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I have found a solution for this problem based on https://github.com/NiGhTTraX/lerna-ts.

The project now contains a file called `tsconfig.build.json` in the project root. This file specifies the compiler options and that test and build files should be excluded from the build process.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "target": "esnext"
  },
  "exclude": ["**/*.test.ts", "**/lib"]
}
```

Another file in the root is `tsconfig.json`. This file is used for type checking outside of the build process, e.g. by Jest and VSCode. This file extends the build configuration. It includes tests by overriding the extended `exclude` configuration. It also contains `noEmit: true`, because processes using TypeScript while developing shouldn’t emit anything. Also it contains the `baseUrl` and `paths` compiler options that are needed to resolve the TypeScript source files at runtime. This is because the `main` field in the packages’ `package.json` files refer the `lib`, which contains the output files.

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.build.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "noEmit": true,
    "paths": {
      "koas-*": ["packages/koas-*/src"]
    }
  },
  "exclude": ["**/lib"]
}
```

Each workspace contains a `tsconfig.build.json` file. This is needed, because it requires the `src` and `outDir` options need to be relative to the tsconfig file. That is used to build the project. It is important this file is **not** named `tsconfig.json`.

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.build.json",
  "include": ["src"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "lib"
  }
}
```

Each workspace also contains a `tsconfig.json`. This can be used to override compiler options for type checking, for example if one repository would use the `dom` typings. This could be omitted.

```json
{
  "extends": "../../tsconfig.json"
}
```

Each workspace has the following `scripts` section in `package.json`. This causes the TypeScript to be compiled when the package is built.

```json
  // …
  "scripts": {
    "prepack": "tsc --project tsconfig.build.json"
  }
```

There are two CI jobs for typechecking. One runs `tsc` to make sure type checking still works in tools using these types in development, the other makes sure building the packages doesn’t break.

```yaml
tsc:
  script:
    - yarn --frozen-lockfile
    - yarn workspaces run tsc

pack:
  script:
    - yarn --frozen-lockfile
    - yarn workspaces run pack
    - find packages -name '*.tgz' -exec mv {} ./ +
  artifacts:
    name: packages
    paths:
      - '*.tgz'
```

Comment: Thank you for carefully phrasing the question and documenting the answer! Does this setup by any chance allow importing files from parent directories, outside the `rootDir`? I can't figure out how TypeScript is supposed to be used in monorepos, where ModuleA wants to import from `../lib/Something`, unless you don't use `rootDir` and `outDir`, and accept that `.js` and `.js.map` files will accompany every `.ts` file and pollute the workspace.

Comment: TypeScript doesn’t allow you to import outside of the root directory. If you wish to use code across multiple packages, create a package for that code and add it as a dependency.

Comment: It is possible but your rootDir needs to include the code you're importing. The only drawback is that code structure in dist has a lot of nesting